# Is it possible to enable using Google Cloud Endpoints Portal without granting extra permissions to access GCP projects on client side?

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I have successfully deployed a Google Cloud Endpoints Developer Portal for my API running on Endpoints. I would like to provide access to testing to people outside my organisation that are not using GCP in their projects.

Login to the portal works correctly if I enable the Service Consumer role for these people (on per-email basis). However, when they open it for the first time, they are being asked to grant some extra permissions to the portal:

[image]

This form can create totally unnecessary security concerns. Does anyone know, why is it needed?

I only would like my clients to be able to test my API using a GUI, before they could start connecting their projects (not necessary on GCP) to mine. This seems to be a valid use case for me, however I might be misunderstanding some basic concepts.

Or should I submit a feature request to Google about a new role that only enables the access to the portal, and nothing else, so no such forms are shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Endpoints APIs must be explicitly shared with customers, the portal needs to verify that the logged-in user has permission to view that Endpoints API. So the short answer is that these scopes are being requested primarily so the portal can check the user's access to this API.

Longer answer is that we (the Endpoints team) are looking into if it's possible to build narrower OAuth scopes that would correspond to the access checks we perform. We agree that it's unnecessarily broad of an access request and are hoping to improve this in the future. Thanks for your comment!